# 404 when trying to clone geckodriver

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am trying to clone this project with mercurial:

```
https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/testing/geckodriver
```

I have downloaded TortoiseHg and selected clone repository.

[image: tortoisehg]

It gives 404 error:

```
% hg clone --verbose https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/testing/geckodriver "D:\Projects\gecko"
HTTP Error: 404 (Not Found)
[command returned code 255 Mon Oct 17 23:12:18 2022]
```

What is the correct path I should be trying to clone?

Comment: That doesn't look like its an hg repository. There is no `.hg` folder there or anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The [URL](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/testing/geckodriver) used everywhere is just the **URL of page** in *some Web-frontend* for the *some repository* in *some state*, loosely connected to *real URL of repository*
2. I don't know the internal structure of Mozilla Central (they can use subrepos for separate projects or have one giant monorepo), but by inspecting changesets, which affected `geckodriver` dir in tree, I [see](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/090b88ecb8ffe5065acabd5f32899b66d0a0cfd2) modified files with path `testing/geckodriver/` in names, based on which I assume that the project of interest is not an independent entity, but only a subtree in a large repository. Thus, because with HG you can't clone just part of tree (contrary to SVN, f.e.), you, maybe, have to clone the whole [Mozilla Central](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central) repository in worst case

---

**PS**: `hg clone -v https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/testing/geckodriver` **will not work**, don't waste time on it

**PPS**: If I grok [docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#sparse) correctly (*NB: it's not guaranteed!!!*) you can enable (still experimental, but bundled for years) sparse extension, prepare sparse-config and try to clone needed subtree `testing/geckodriver` (it will be **not** dumb `hg clone`, but `hg init`, hack-hack hgrc, `hg pull https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central` in order to have limiting sparse-profile in game on getting sources)